# How do I calculate p-value for trend across categories in R?

Tags: r, trend, ancova, contrasts, lsmeans

I am using R to make a table describing my dataset. My goal is to estimate the adjusted mean of a continuous variable across different groups (e.g. age groups, BMI categories) and calculate a p-value for the trend (across ordered groups) or heterogeneity (in unordered groups).

I am using this code for the means and heterogeneity p-values:

```
require(emmeans)
mydata$bmi_cat <- factor(bmi_cat, ordered = TRUE)
lm_bmi <- lm(hdl ~ age + sex + bmi_cat, mydata)
emmeans(lm_bmi, c("bmi_cat"), contr="pairwise", adjust="none")
```

... but I am having some trouble working out how to get the trend p-values. I've tried two approaches and I am getting different results, and I don't know why. The first way is using the contr="poly" argument in emmeans and the second way is using aov and then summary with a split argument. The p-values for the quadratic trends match, but I am getting different results for the linear trend in aov versus lm and emmeans.

What is different about these two methods? Which should I use? And is my code for estimating adjusted means and heterogeneity p-values okay? Thanks!

```
#### SAMPLE CODE ####

require(emmeans)
iris$Species_Order <- factor(iris$Species, ordered=TRUE)

#### Linear p-value is 2.08E-13 in lm summary, quadratic is 9.66E-13
summary(iris_lm)
iris_lm <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Species_Order, data=iris)

#### Same results using lm fitted model in emmeans function
emm_summary <- summary(emmeans(iris_lm, "Species_Order", contr="poly"))
emm_summary$contrasts$p.value

#### Different linear p-value (1.82E-07) from aov summary (quadratic unchanged)
iris_aov <- aov(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Species_Order, data=iris)
summary(iris_aov, split=list(Species_Order=list(linear=1,quadratic=2)))

#### Still get original result if applying emmeans to model fitted with aov function
summary(emmeans(iris_aov, "Species_Order", contr="poly"))$contrasts$p.value
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped to show the actual output. The one result is

```
> summary(iris_aov, split = list(Species_Order=list(linear=1,quadratic=2)))
                            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)
Petal.Width                  1  430.5   430.5 3016.79  < 2e-16
Species_Order                2   13.0     6.5   45.59 4.14e-16
  Species_Order: linear      1    4.3     4.3   30.02 1.82e-07
  Species_Order: quadratic   1    8.7     8.7   61.16 9.66e-13
Residuals                  146   20.8     0.1
```

The linear and quadratic parts here are computed *sequentially* -- the linear part, unadjusted, followed by the quadratic part, adjusted for the linear effect.

The `emmeans` results are, after forcing extra precision:

```
> data.frame(emmeans(iris_aov, poly ~ Species_Order)$contrasts)
   contrast  estimate        SE  df   t.ratio      p.value
1    linear  2.276693 0.2813245 146  8.092764 2.081762e-13
2 quadratic -1.118890 0.1430742 146 -7.820347 9.659576e-13
```

These are *partial* *t* tests of each effect. So (unlike before), the test of the linear effect is adjusted for the quadratic effect. The test of the quadratic effect is adjusted for the linear effect, as before, yielding the same result.

Another way to get this is to summarize the regression coefficients:

```
> summary.lm(iris_aov) $ coefficients
                  Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)      2.5362252 0.18517526 13.696350 5.558718e-28
Petal.Width      1.0187116 0.15224171  6.691410 4.409235e-10
Species_Order.L  1.6098653 0.19892650  8.092764 2.081762e-13
Species_Order.Q -0.4567848 0.05840978 -7.820347 9.659576e-13
```

These too are *partial* *t* tests. The estimates from `emmeans` are scaled differently, but they have the same *t* ratios and *p* values.

BTW, unless there is an `Error()` term in the model, the only difference between `lm` and `aov` is how the object is summarized.

Comment: Thanks very much, this was really helpful.